# A WMS layer does not seem to load correctly in projection

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, wms

No idea how to ask this I am quite new to GIS.
I am trying to load this WMS service `https://geoservices.informatievlaanderen.be/raadpleegdiensten/GRB-basiskaart-grijs/wms` with [EPSG:3812](http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3812) but every time it is cut off halfway a province

[image]

The reason I need EPSG:3812 is that I want to put a layer on top off it and that layer only is available in EPSG:3812. If I add the above layer with EPSG:3856 for instance it loads perfectly but then the EPSG:3812 layer has jagged edges and I want as sharp an image as possible so I guess they both have to be the same CRS?

Comment: services don't have to be in the same CRS, but if he CRS is not available in the service, (not an issue here) then QGIS will need to do some reprojection of the fetched data.  Requesting EPSG:3812 shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: The extent of the data in the service for the single layer is `<BoundingBox maxy="745000" maxx="759000" miny="650000" minx="552000" CRS="EPSG:3812"/>` what is the limit of the boundary shown in your image?

Comment: What version of QGIS are you using?